# LSTM for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I saw this tensorflow model which is used for telling if text is positive or negative, and I don't fully understand it. I know that LSTM saves the words and predict the next words based on the previous words, but how does this help network to distinguish emotions of the text?

```
def tensorflow_based_model(): 
    inputs = Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])
    layer = Embedding(2000,50,input_length=max_len)(inputs) 
    layer = LSTM(64)(layer)
    layer = Dense(256,name='FC1')(layer) 
    layer = Activation('relu')(layer) 
    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(1,name='out_layer')(layer) 
    layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer) 
    model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=layer) 
    return model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough LSTM can be used in the text generation, the main use of LSTM (or any recurrent neural network layer) is to understand sequences. You can find more information in this blog posts:

[The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](https://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)

[Understanding LSTM Networks](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

In the case of sentiment analysis, Instead of helping to generate new word, LSTM helps us understand what was said. It basicaly reads over the string and keeps some important information about the previously said words.

Comment: Why is there an activation sigmoid function? ( I thought it's already inside lstm architecture) And what is the purpose of Activation relu layer? (I know it can be replaced by tanh which is also already inside lstm)

Comment: The sigmoid is used for binary classification task which is the problem we are trying to solve (positive vs negative). The purpose of using activation layer is to create non linear feature representation. If we were to use just linear functions in the NN, we end up not learning more feature but just copy of inputs. Which end up becoming logistic regression with extra steps. So it is essential part of deep learning. When it comes to chosing relu or tanh is up to you. They both have their advantages and disadvantages.